# How to add tags to my fluentd events

Tags: fluentd

I write

```
<source>
  @type tail
  format nginx
  path /home/work/opt/nginx/var/log/access.log
  tag nginx.access
</source>
```

in my fluent.conf file and match to stdout,but when i make a post call to my website,nginx log access into its log,but fluentd_ui suggest

```
 [warn]: no patterns matched tag="nginx.access"
```

how to add tag to my http request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<source>
   @type tail
   path /var/log/nginx/access.log
   pos_file /var/log/access.log.pos
   tag apache.access
   format nginx
</source>

<match apache.access>
   @type stdout
</match>
```

Try running this conf file code. I think you will be able to solve your problem!!